# You must wait 0 hours before answering your own question?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When answering your own question, it currently says:

> You must wait 0 hours before answering your own question

And it won't let me accept my own answer.

I *did* wait 48 hours.
It was after the 48 hour time limit that it said I had "0 hours" to wait, and it would still not accept my own answer.
Perhaps only minutes were left (i.e. < 1 hour).
It should indicate that.

Comment: I started a new thread offering a suggestion to the weird/unclear wording about the "0 hours" part [1].  I figured it would be off-topic in this thread, yet still related.

[1] http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/wording-suggestion-for-the-you-must-wait-x-hours-before-accepting-your-own-answe

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait 48 hours before accepting your answer on your own question.

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

You should be able to answer it immediately, however, or [after a shorter wait, if you have less than 100 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).

Answer (score 3):

You can answer your question immediately. The 48 hour limit is for **accepting** your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the amount of time remaining is rounded DOWN (or NEAREST) when it should be rounded UP.

Decrementing time should be rounded up, so that, for example, if 48 hours are allocated, then the remaining time should only decrement to 47 hours after one hour has passed (rather than immediately), 46 hours after 2 hours have passed, etc, and so that for the last one hour, it says "1 hour" (not "0 hours" or something like that).