# What's the waiting period for new users to answer their own questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, self-answer

I suggested a new user answer [his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735719/still-get-error-popup-even-when-applyupdates-is-inside-try-except), but he says he was denied (emphasis added):

> New users can't answer their own question for **24** hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead.

I wasn't aware of that rule until today, but supposedly, [the actual waiting period is just **8** hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186). Is the waiting period back to 24 hours again, or has the error-message text just not been updated yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or has the error-message text just not been updated yet?

The error message was hard-coded for some reason. I just un-hard-coded it. We're usually really good about not hard-coding values like that.

(spins wheel of blame)

Comment: :-) Before this, I even [changed Hendrik's edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/86186/revisions) to allow one to find the message using the 8 hours. Now it seems he was right after all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Jeff's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186)

> if you attempt to answer your own question within 8 hours of **posting it**

He tried it after 6 hours of his post, but error msg should be fixed as its not 24 hours.

[image]