# New user restriction on Stack Overflow reset on account creation on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, new-users, linked-accounts

A week or so ago I had provided an answer on SO to one of my own questions. Today I was tempted to do the same but thought I should see if there was any info on the subject. I created an account on MSO to find out the etiquette around this.

After I created the account and read some of the answers, I went and proceeded to answer my question. Upon submitting it stated that new users are not allowed to answer their own question within the first 8 hours.

Is this restiction cleared if you have 100% for "remove new user restrictions"?

Seems the new account on MSO is being applied to my response on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For answering your own question, the time-limit restriction is actually relaxed when you reach a reputation of 100, not 10.  So it is just a different definition of "new user" between the warning message and the privilege.  Nothing to do with your new meta account.

See: [Minimum reputation for answering your own question should be higher than what is needed to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186)

Answer (score 2):

You get that error message if you have [less than 100 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186). You were able to answer your question [last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749607/best-way-to-present-a-hierarchy-of-options-for-selection-in-mvc-razor-view) because you answered ~20 hours after you asked; the creation of a meta account had nothing to do with it