# Answering own question now has 8 hour limit?

Tags: support, answers

I just got the following on SO:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> New users can't answer their own
>   question for 8 hours. Please use
>   comments, or edit your question
>   instead.

Is this new?  I have answered my own questions previously within 8 hours.  How long is a member tagged as a *New User*?

Comment: Yes! Until you get 100 reps, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is - and try again, I've kicked your reps up.

Comment: aw shucks, just saw that, thanks & much appreciated.

Comment: The "new user" is not official title, but for this specific case it means less than 100 reputation as YOU mentioned. Anyway, please change the "bug" tag so something else, either support or discussion. :) BTW you can see all changes [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) - useful to track.

Comment: Wasn't that a 24 hour limit?

Comment: @bobby it was, but we reduced it to 8 hours after some testing and input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason we have that restriction is because a lot of new users tend to "answer" their own questions by posting messageboard style.

As others noted, this restriction is lifted at 100 reputation.

Comment: +1 for explaining what they ought to do in the error message.