# What's the best way to post a tutorial?

Tags: discussion, tutorials

I went looking for answers to a question I had, but didn't find what I was looking for.  Now that I've found the answer myself, I'd like to share what I've learned.

What's the best way to do this, if nobody else has asked the exact question I did?  Should I ask the question myself, and immediately post my own answer?  Or should I mark the question as a tutorial in the title?  ("Tutorial: How to ABC when using XYZ")

Comment: I think that if the tutorial is related to a Stack Overflow collective, it might be suggested as a collective's article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a question, and answer it yourself. I've done this a few times, and it's even in the official FAQ:

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long
> as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy and
> phrase it in the form of a question.

Comment: I think you just have to wait a certain amount of time (depending on your rep) before you can answer your own question. I think it starts out at something like 8-24 hours.

Comment: You can answer immediately but you must wait before accepting

Comment: You have to actually wait 8 hours unless you have 100 rep: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89063/answering-own-question-now-has-8-hour-limit

Answer (score 9):

That's not what the site is designed for.

Of course you can create your tutorial elsewhere and **when applicable** use it as resource for answering questions, but be sure to include the relevant information in the answer. Don't just post a link to your tutorial.

If you intend to ask a question and then answer it in order to make a "tutorial", do so cautiously. Make sure it is not a duplicate and make sure your information is accurate and conclusive.

Answer (score 8):

All questions on Stack Overflow have to conform to the Q&A format.  That means that your proposed tutorial will be subject to the same requirements as any other question; it must be on-topic, answerable, constructive and of interest to others.

If you can accomplish those things, go for it.  To improve your chances, include the complete answer with your question, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/1288).

Comment: Also make sure the question isn't "too broad".  That seems to be the most applicable close reason for questions of this form.