# publish learning in stackoverflow

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to post a tutorial on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-tutorial-on-so)

I have a particular learning regarding a topic in iOS which I would like to share.

Since it is not a question, I was wondering on how to post it on StackOverflow?
Should I post it as a regular question? Or is there another way to do so?

Comment: Imagine a question where your article would be the perfect answer. Ask the question and answer it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: When you say learning, do you mean something like a tutorial or guide? See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-tutorial-on-so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "learning," but in general: if it's not a question, you should not post it as a question. If it answers someone else's question, you could post it as an answer to that question.

If you just have some information you'd like to share, your personal blog or website would probably be an appropriate place, but that sort of post doesn't really fit anywhere on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow isn't a blog - it's a Q&A system. If you have something that doesn't fit that then chat is probably the most appropriate place to discuss it.

Alternatively if it's a useful problem and you can make it into a good question which you also happen give a good answer to yourself then that's fine.