# Will I get downvoted if I put the strict question with no much research in it but will provide more research in my own answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Will I get downvoted if I put the strict question with no much research in it but will provide more research in my own answer? I suppose reviewers won't see easily see that I provided the answer to my own so they won't bother and would simply downvote. Any suggestions here?

Comment: If you've done the research, why not put it in the question? If you haven't, do it before you ask the question.

Comment: Questions that show you performed research or are not clear are likely to be downvoted

Comment: I'm getting downvoted on this one much for some reason :) Will this question get deleted eventually? Asking because still, I think it has a pretty good answer.

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256644/997587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. I've posted questions that were seemingly basic but *showing* you did your homework, or at least talking about the question *in depth* is handy.

You can talk about the *problem* - talk about failed attempts, or even what you've tried that *failed*, then cap it off with a glorious total victory of an answer.

*Self answer* does not mean *phone in the question*

Consider this [question on gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304793/how-do-i-disable-the-power-grid-in-the-seoul-power-plant) I've posted

I've talked about what I need, what I tried, and how it doesn't work. Its not exactly war and peace, but it gives a reader all the information I had.

Then I self answered cause *that was too hard* and I wanted others to find it. (And they did! Much to my shock!)

So - post a question talking about what you *tried* or at least *what you're trying to do* and you should be fine. Just imagine you're playing [jeopardy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).