# Allow short questions if the Answer My Question box is checked

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

I wrote up a pretty short and succinct question on the Mechanics site, and wrote up a very long answer using the [Answer Your Question checkbox](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  When I tried to post the q/a, it told me that I needed a more complete question.  This restriction doesn't make sense when people are trying to post both sides (questions and answers).  If they already have a good answer, it seems safe to trust that they have a decent understanding of what their question was.

My question was a pretty simple one:

> How would one go about recharging the Air Conditioning system on a car?

I meant it to be a sort of canonical question, since it so happens that the procedure is pretty much the same between cars.  I ended up adding another sentence about how my car's cooling power just wasn't what it used to be, and it posted, but it still seems like a Q/A would be fine without some of those checks.

**Can we get rid of (at least some of) the quality restrictions on questions if the Answer My Own Question box is checked?**

Comment: The minimum question length is like 30 characters... It's not onerous. Guessing there was something else... Quote what you tried to post?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's great that you want to share your knowledge with a self-answer, but you *also* need to make the question thorough enough that somebody else could have answered it too (or could still, because maybe somebody has a different approach to your problem).

We evaluate question quality based on the *question*, not the answers.  Whether it's a self-answer or a poorly-asked question that somebody still manages to divine the intent behind and answer, the question should be improved so it's available to everybody.  When self-answering you need to be especially careful of this; because you already know the answer it's easy to leave out important information even though you intend to ask a good question.

Comment: Good answer.  I do think that there are questions that a short block of text would suffice for, but I can see how that won't be true for most questions.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256654/165773 :)

Comment: @gnat oh wow; I forgot all about that.  I've written basically this answer on several child metas over the years, and didn't remember doing so here too.

Answer (score 8):

Well...why?  Self answering a question doesn't automatically make it exempt from the quality standards inherent in each site.  Even if you're self answering, the question is still judged on it's own.  If it's too broad or opinionated, it's still going to get closed.  So bypassing even the minimum of quality controls for questions doesn't make any sense.