# Why can't I post responses to my own question or accept multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

I am new to this site and I find it a little confusing.

I've posted a new question:

1. Why can I not write a new post to my own thread?
    As far as I can see I may only write comments to the other's answers.
    But, what if I would like to ask a further question, post some code again, etc. 
    (I cannot do this in a comment)...
2. Why can I not accept more than 1 answer to my question?
    I think that is unfair when I cannot confirm that the help of two persons was neeeded?
3. Something has changed in my thread and when I had accepted one answer, other answers disappeared... why?

Comment: It's important to note that SO is **not** a forum. It doesn't behave in the same way, and approaching it as if it was one **will** lead to confusion.

Comment: Even as a brand-new user, you should still be able to post answers.  You can post an answer to your own question immediately, but cannot accept it until a certain period of tome (not sure if it's 24 or 48 hours) has passed.

Comment: 1. Yes I can Edit, but adding additional code or text to my question may lead to confusion for others who read my question. 2. My account allowed me to upvote only 1 answer as far as I remember ...

Comment: hmm thanks, initially I thought that posting an answer to my own question closes my thread, Ok, That is a solution :)

Comment: @user161496 Users of Stack Exchange would be more confused by extra information appearing in answers than by it appearing in the question. The accepted practice is to edit your question to include extra info. Using answers for that will result in those answers being removed anyway, since they don't actually *answer* the question.

Comment: @user161496: Please don't post an answer to your own question unless it actually **is** an answer to the original problem - if you have another problem, ask another question; if you have more information to provide to answerers regarding the original problem then edit your existing question.

Comment: @user740144 - if your rep is under 15 you won't be able to upvote, but once you hit 15 rep you can give an upvote to each answer you find helpful, then mark the one that best answered your question as the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all of you for clarifications

Comment: @Iszi: No, [you **cannot** post an answer to your own question immediately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186) if you're below 100 rep.

Comment: @HendrikVogt - Hm.  Maybe they should add that to /privileges ?  That's what I was basing my statement on, mostly.

Comment: @Iszi: Maybe that's not important enough for `/privileges` - you can answer your own question after 8 hours anyway.

Comment: @user161496: I would suggest you make actual accounts both here and on SO; right now, you're showing up as two distinct users in this question, probably due to the migration from SO...

Answer (score 12):

1. You can edit your question if you want to clarify it.
2. You can upvote as many answers as you like if you want to express appreciation.
3. Sometimes people delete their answers if they feel they are not adding value to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it's for questions and answers.  In this format, it wouldn't make sense for you to reply to your own question.  If you had the answer, you probably wouldn't be asking in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: you *can* write answer to your own question, this can be useful for example if you found the solution yourself and want to share it.
If you don't see the "Post Answer" button or getting error clicking it, let us know.

Your second issue has valid point, but as things stands now only one answer can be accepted so in case of more than one correct answers just accept the one which helped you most and upvote the others.