# Trouble with new-user restrictions

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, documentation

I spent a long time writing the answer I found to a question that I asked and only after I hit submit, I got this:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>   New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Besides that fact that my privileges page shows that I am not a new user, why is there no warning about this beforehand?
The third thing from the bottom of stackoverflow.com/privileges (when I go to it) is

> [remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user)          100%

Separately, do I need to do something to have the restriction-removal take effect? There is no documentation that I could find that says that.

Comment: Privileges unlock automatically (and instantly) as you gain reputation.  I don't know what the minimum is here.

Comment: Here's the original "documentation": [Minimum reputation for answering your own question should be higher than what is needed to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just edited the copy

New copy is:

> > Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead."

This check is really important, historically we got lots of new users that treat SO like a BBS, and start a discussion on their own question. This feature stops a lot of the noise.

Apologies for the collateral damage.

Comment: Thanks. Well, maybe before tonight is over I will have 100. Will you add it to the privileges page too?

Comment: does your fix also save users from wasting their time crafting an answer that you subsequently reject?

Comment: @Benjol not really, but we do save a draft, I wonder if they can get at it. Agree we should stop them earlier

Comment: A couple of words on BBS (real brief)... please? Guessing its meaning being Bulletin Board System, I'm unsure about its cons .. Thanks. (BBS seems to be behind my time)

Comment: BBS = bulletin board system

Answer (score 1):

You need to get some amount of reputation to be considered "old"; probably between 25 and 100.

I can't find any documentation of that, though.

Comment: It's not in http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/

Comment: The third thing from the bottom of stackoverflow.com/privileges (when I go to it) is   
"remove new user restrictions      100%"

Comment: Surely this must be a bug.  The page even mentions that `the first few upvotes on your questions or answers will quickly elevate you out of it!`  @yakatz clearly exceeded that and shouldn't be considered a restricted new user.