# Are useful/unusual techniques shared via a question welcomed?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

I've had to solve an irritatingly complex problem - I think this solution would be of use to other developers.

In brief, I've got an .Net4/MVC3 web app which supports the concept of scheduled jobs. There's a windows service which executes the jobs.

Every time we publish (using deployment), the windows service detects the changes to the website DLLs, sends a graceful termination signal to all running jobs and waits for them to terminate. In parallel, it creates a new AppDomain and loads the [new] DLLs from the website then scans for any classes which implement `IJob`, reads any relevant attributes and executes the code in line with the defined schedule (technically, each class implements a `bool ShouldExecute()` which can be polled and allows for complex logic.

Benefits include: No additional steps during deployment, shared container/IoC config, very robust, etc...

So... Should I post this as a Q/A on SO?

I'm not sure how I should tag this Q so any improvements appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you can word it as a pair of question and corresponding answer (i.e. not put the answer in the question itself).

Also note that [new users need to wait 8 hours before being allowed to answer their own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).