# Why can't I immediately self-answer as a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki, new-users

Why is it not possible to self-answer your own question immediately while marking it as *community wiki*?

As I understand it, with a community wiki answer you won't get any points out of it, and it's thus almost guaranteed that this kind of answer won't be abusing (in whatever way it's possible) Stack Overflow itself.

Also, the rationale for restricting almost everything to users with a low score, is to avoid abuse to the system in the first place. Thus, I don't get it. I'd be willing to post an answer that I spent a good chunk of time looking for, even without gaining any points for it: only for the good of others interested out there. Yet I can't do it until 8 hours are passed.

Comment: most things that "need" to be community wiki shouldn't exist in the first place. Can you provide a specific example of your question and answer?

Comment: sure:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580921/how-does-go-implement-garbage-collection
Instead of keeping the tab opened, or resorting on the draft, I chose to just add it to the question itself as an edit, but this solution is quite unclean

PS if @JeffAtwood or someone else wants to add my answer as a "proper answer" and remove it from the question body, that would be fine :)

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for StackOverflow either...voting to close.

Comment: @sixlettervariables where it should be posted then? there're other examples of questions about garbage collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732013/does-garbage-collection-work-with-the-go-compiler-gc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431720/how-does-garbage-collection-in-java-work

Comment: @berdario: the big difference is those are actual questions. Yours was just some placeholder. You even alluded to this in the soliloquy you included in the question body.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I think that "How does Go programming language implement garbage collection" is an actual and legitimate question... obviously, once said that, there's not much else left to write in the body of the question, but just look at other similar questions that ask for a single definition/fact: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this question as for *why* self-answers within 8 hours are not allowed for low-rep users: [Minimum reputation for answering your own question should be higher than what is needed to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86185). This is all about preventing non-answers, and it has nothing to do with community wiki, so it's quite correct that you have to wait these 8 hours.

So just compose your answer right now, and submit it in 8 hours without making it community wiki – that may even give you some reputation, and next time you won't have to wait 8 hours. You have two possibilities here: either leave a browser tab open with your completed answer, or rely on the draft that will be saved after 45 seconds. However, for the latter option note that [the draft will be cleared if you post other answers in the meantime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238).

Comment: Still, the point is, if you already know what to answer, why not post it? Even Jeff said: *> It would prevent new users from posting legitimate self-answers when they solve their own problems.*. Making that community-wiki would be something even better.

Comment: The initial suggestion was to _prevent_ low rep users from answering own questions, and this is what Jeff was referring to. So it was made an 8-hour waiting time instead.

Comment: I see, btw the idea would be that if someone is considering to make an answer into a community wiki, it would hardly be a non-aswer

Comment: @berdario: I completely understand your point of view, but (even if it's hard to believe) there would be users who try to post non-answers, it doesn't work, so they'll think "ah, forgot to put the checkmark in that box" ...