# Document "self answer more quickly" in privilege lists

Tags: feature-request, privileges, self-answer, faq-update-request

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86186/38765 states that you need a minimum of 100 rep to answer your own question within 8 hours.

This isn't mentioned in the privileges that are gained at 100 rep (which are [create chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) and [edit community wiki posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki)), or the 10 rep [Remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user).

I sometimes have to look up this privilege so I can respond to people saying "Why are you answering your question in a comment rather than an answer?" to new users.

Comment: You can't just wait out the 8 hours?  Or get 100 rep?

Comment: @RobertHarvey lots of people don't bother to wait.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If by "you" you mean "random drive-by users"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So slindsey3000 in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319567/top-level-methods-why-they-become-private-instance-methods-in-object-why-not-p) shouldn't have posted that he worked it out until the 8 hours are up?

Comment: If the rule is no good, it should be abolished.  I suspect, however, that it was put in for a good reason.

Comment: Also: pinging @Waffles to please let 'er rip :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added [the note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) about self-answer privilege to Meta's privilege, waffles(or someone from the dev team) will have to put this to the rest of the sites.