# Is there a way for us to monitor new questions that leverage "Answer your own question"

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, self-answer

As noted in the blog, users can now answer their own questions while asking it.

I'm curious to monitor how people use this feature.  I'm wondering if there is any tool/filter (perhaps just for 10k+ users) that allows us to keep an eye on such questions.  I have some concerns over how they will be moderated when they are dups, off-topic, etc. and would like to see for myself whether such concern is warranted.

Comment: How I wish this were a self-answered question.

Comment: It crossed my mind, but alas, I had nothing to offer. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As Jeff notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/is-there-a-way-for-us-to-monitor-new-questions-that-leverage-answer-your-own-qu/133360#133360), this has been possible since day one - there are thousands of them on Stack Overflow. So you can just write a query (with human tolerances, since practically-speaking answering <= 1 second after asking is a bit tricky without the checkbox):

- [Questions self-answered within 60 seconds](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70962/top-self-answered-questions?Delay=60)

Note that plenty of these do attract alternate answers, and the asker's own answer isn't always the one rated most useful by the voters. Self-answering offers you the challenge of writing both a good question *and* a good answer; if you fail at either one of these, the community will let you know.

Comment: That query is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

What need is there? How is this different than any other SO question and answer(s)?

Other than the answer coming in at exactly the same time as the question -- which you could easily duplicate by **having your answer pre-composed** at the time you ask the question, then pasting it in immediately after asking -- it's subject to all the same voting, bumping, and review processes as every other question, whether they are self-answered or not.

(Yes, it is true that [we eventually started blocking under 100 rep users from self-answering for 8 hours due to abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185), but that's still an edge case at best, and didn't even start until mid 2011.)

Comment: Clearly, I haven't figured out the right way to use this feature, because my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css/10711731#10711731) came 1 second after the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css).

Comment: Why not just monitor all self-answers (whether via checkbox or pre-compose)?