# Is it possible to search self-answers using the advanced search?

Tags: support, search, self-answer

Is there a way to find self-answers with the advanced search?

Preferably, not using the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and including results of all time and not just the recent ones with the new *share your knowledge, Q&A-style*

Comment: I'm inclined to say "No".

Comment: Why don't you want to use the data explorer?

Comment: @Lix I want flexibility with tags and keywords

Comment: You can have variables in your queries there...

Comment: @Lix to be sincere, I am pretty new to data explorer, never wrote a single query... It looks too confusing and I don't like asking to people to write things for me... It is so confusing that I will probably take less time searching them manually hehehe

Comment: Why don't you take an existing query and modify it to your needs?

Comment: @Lix maybe I am wrong, but I think all your 3 comments are kind of trying to insult me in a some way... I will try to ignore you >:(

Comment: @aja - If my comments came across as insulting, I apologize - **this was not my intention.**  All I am trying to say is that the functionality you are looking for already exists in the data explorer and saying `"I am pretty new to data explorer, never wrote a single query... It looks too confusing"` is simply not a good enough reason for someone else to write you the query.

Comment: If someone wrote in a question on SO proper saying - `"I am new to jQuery and the documentation is confusing so please help me write this in JavaScript"` - it would not be received to well...

Comment: @Lix and now you are saying I am a "write me tah codez plx!" person?, I [clearly said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135675/is-it-possible-to-search-self-answers-using-the-advanced-search#comment378672_135675) "I don't like asking to people to write things for me", that is actually one of the reasons I first tried to find an advanced-search way, because I know I won't have luck if I ask what you think I asked

Comment: @ajax, for what it's worth, on my [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/is-there-a-way-for-us-to-monitor-new-questions-that-leverage-answer-your-own-qu), I received a helpful tip on [just such a data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70962/top-self-answered-questions?Delay=60).

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to search for self-answered questions with advanced search. The only option is to use the Data Explorer.

Here is a [search query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) that I wrote, which searches all answers to *your questions*. It can be used to find self answers as well.