# How to search for my self-answered question?

Tags: feature-request, support, search

I want to search a question of mine which contains an answer posted by myself.

I have tried `user:me is:question is:answer` but this returns all questions and all answers posted by me.

But I want to search only for my questions which contain my answer.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

This would be better if this feature would be added in future:

```
user:me is:question + is:answer
```

Or

```
user:me is:question And is:answer
```

Comment: This is all questions with me and all answers with me but I want to search only my question which contains my answer.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I [suspect this isn't possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but I'm not 100% positive all of the ninja search operators are documented (those experimental may not be). I believe search doesn't have the reasoning to see something as a question _and_ an answer, but I'm going to check on that.

Comment: Similar: [Is it possible to search self-answers using the advanced search?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135675/is-it-possible-to-search-self-answers-using-the-advanced-search)

Comment: You only have 22 questions on SO.  Why not just go through them?

Comment: My friend was asking about this in SO...

Comment: If you don't mind Data Explorer, you can use a query like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/130546/self-answered-questions-based-on-user-id). The caveat is the database there is only updated weekly, so you won't get the most recent results.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to look at your questions, just use your profile. If you want to look at someone else's use theirs.

Anyways, to answer your question, your syntax is incorrect. That syntax suggests you are looking for a post that is *both* a question and answer. What it should be is:

```
user:me is:question OR is:answer
```

Comment: I think he wants is:question AND is:answer to find his self answered questions, which I'm reasonably sure isn't implemented. `is` sets the target to a question _or_ answer, which is the problem, he wants both.

Comment: @TimPost that was told in the comments, not the question, so I took a shot in the dark.

Comment: Yes, this is one of those odd scenarios - I found it equally hard to articulate why I think it's not yet possible to do :)