# Searching for questions with a self answer

Tags: support, search, self-answer

I wanted to check what had happened to a question I read last night, but the only useful thing I can remember about it is that it was self answered. I can't remember the user's name, or any good keywords in the question. I also use the app, so I don't have a history to reference.

Is there a way using the in-site search to find questions with self answers?

This was on SO, but I figured any answer would likely also be applicable on other sites, so I'm posting this here.

Comment: Not useful now as SEDE only updates once a week but here is a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/843022)  that lists recent self-answers.

Comment: @rene Oh, cool, thanks. I need to learn how to use SEDE one of these days...and relearn SQL.

Comment: Pro-Tip: Check and search your browser history.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I use the app, which doesn't have a history.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you might like the [tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) in that case.

Comment: @rene Thanks. Ya, definitely overdue.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308173/380725

Comment: SO is very busy, you can't search anything with such a vague criteria.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh That does appear to be a dupe. Thanks. Idk why I couldn't find that using Google.

Comment: @user202729 I was wondering if the was an `is...:` search option that might help, or something similar.

Comment: The SEDE query isn't an exact answer, but the question is a duplicate, and I suspect that's as good as its getting.